# Calculating the Variance of a Dice Roll?

Tags: probability

Here's my thinking:

$$Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$$

Assuming each roll is independent:

$$E(X^2) = E(XX) = E(X) \cdot E(X) = E(X)^2$$

Thus:

$$Var(X) = 0$$

However, this is not correct. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X^2]\ne\mathbb{E}[X]^2$ which is what you're saying. Note that: $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\sum^6_{i=1}g(i)\mathbb{P}(X=i)$

Comment: You treated $X$ as independent of itself.  That is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general:

$\mathbb{E}[X^2]\ne\mathbb{E}[X]^2$ - your claim is that these are equal!

Note that: $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\sum^6_{i=1}g(i)\mathbb{P}(X=i)$

Here: $g(i)=i^2$ and of course $\mathbb{P}(X=i)=\frac{1}{6}$

So:

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\frac{1}{6}\sum^6_{i=1}i^2$$ and is clearly $\ne\frac{1}{36}(\sum_{i=1}^6i)^2$ if you work these out. Thus variance is non-zero

(more info: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Variance )

Comment: I just always thought that $E(xy) = E(x)*E(y)$ assuming independence?

Comment: The value of $X$ is not independent from the value of $X$

Comment: @xyy any more questions, I'd quite like that tick!

Answer (score 0):

Your step $E(x^2)=[E(x)]^2$ is not correct. As there are only six cases you can calculate $E(x^2)$ from the definition.  You will find it is greater than $(E(x))^2$  This is because large values are weighted more.

Comment: I just always thought that E(xy)=E(x)∗E(y) assuming independence?

Comment: No, $x$ and $x$ are *not* independent.  For any given roll, they are the same.  We know $E(x)=3.5$, so $(E(x))^2=12.25$  Now compute $E(x^2)=\frac 16(1^2+2^2+\dots 6^2)$